# How do I simplify my long and redundant jquery code?

Tags: jquery

##newbie here##
I have a long code and would like to simplify it. I would appreciate your help. Thank you!
And fm and mo value is incrementing. It does not ends in fm5 but incrementing as per list provided.

here is my code -->

```
$('.fm1').hover(function() {
    $( this ).siblings('.featured-wrap').find('.mo1').toggleClass('active');
});
$('.fm2').hover(function() {
    $( this ).siblings('.featured-wrap').find('.mo2').toggleClass('active');
});
$('.fm3').hover(function() {
    $( this ).siblings('.featured-wrap').find('.mo3').toggleClass('active');
});
$('.fm4').hover(function() {
    $( this ).siblings('.featured-wrap').find('.mo4').toggleClass('active');
});
$('.fm5').hover(function() {
    $( this ).siblings('.featured-wrap').find('.mo5').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the same class for all the `.fmX`, and put the incrementing number in a data attribute.

```html
<div class="fm" data-index="1"></div>
<div class="fm" data-index="2"></div>
<div class="fm" data-index="3"></div>
```

Then you can bind a single handler, which uses that data value to select the related class to toggle.

```js
$(".fm").hover(function() {
    var index = $(this).data("index");
    $(this).siblings(".featured-wrap".find(".mo"+index).toggleClass("active");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `HTML` of the below snippet you could do something like the following:

```js
$('div[class^=fm]').on('mouseover mouseout', (e) => {
  let index = Object.values($(e.target)[0].classList).filter(x => /^fm/.test(x))[0].replace('fm', '');
  $('.mo' + index).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="fm3 otherclass">
  fm3
</div>
<div class="featured-wrap">
  <div class="someclass">
    <div class="mo3 anotherclass">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="fm4 otherclass">
  fm4
</div>
<div class="featured-wrap">
  <div class="someclass">
    <div class="mo4 anotherclass">
      4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="fm1 otherclass">
  fm1
</div>
<div class="featured-wrap">
  <div class="someclass">
    <div class="mo1 anotherclass">
      1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="fm2 otherclass">
  fm2
</div>
<div class="featured-wrap">
  <div class="someclass">
    <div class="mo2 anotherclass">
      2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```